# DjangoCMS render_model with HTML

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm using Django CMS and the Aldryn News Blog app on a client site to display a blog listing. The default template code uses

```
{% render_model article "lead_in" %}
```

to display the "Lead in" excerpt text. However it is displaying p tags for me and I actually need them to render.

https://pasteboard.co/GSq8XObQ.png
https://pasteboard.co/GSq8ONF.png

I have tried both:

```
{% autoescape off %}
{% render_model article "lead_in" %}
{% endautoescape %}



{% render_model article "lead_in" |safe %}
```

The first does nothing and the second errors out. How can I get it to render the html tags?

Comment: What is the error you're getting when using safe?

Comment: @AlexanderBrill Could not find variable at start of |safe.
Also it is rendering html after a while, which is the strangest thing. If I wait and come back to the page after some time it will render properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this solution?

```
{{ article.lead_in|safe }}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks. Not sure why the app itself didn't go this route :)